# beforeFilter in 2.1 is not called

Tags: cakephp

I have upgraded to 2.1 from 1.3 and beforeFilter() is no longer called. They all have parent::beforeFilter() calls so its nothing like that.

Debugging the Events code I found that hard coding this method to return false, the beforeFilter() runs.

https://github.com/cakephp/cakephp/blob/2.1/lib/Cake/Event/CakeEvent.php#L130

Anyone know where and why this has been set to false?

Debugging more, the [stopPropgation](https://github.com/cakephp/cakephp/blob/2.1/lib/Cake/Event/CakeEvent.php#L120) method is called when [this](https://github.com/cakephp/cakephp/blob/2.1/lib/Cake/Event/CakeEventManager.php#L245) fails. The contents of $listener['callable'] at that point is the ComponentCollection object

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Turns out there was a Component that returned false in one of the initialize methods and that killed the whole process.

Comment: mark your own answer correct when the time limit on doing so runs out.

Comment: I've used this site before, captain obvious.

Comment: sorry - I meant that to be a comment on a new user's question I had just had open in a different tab. My bad, forgive me Captain CrankyPants.